# How to achieve following graphics via css

Tags: html, css

I've set my self a challenge to develop a website without using a single image. I'll mainly use icon fonts, but for this particle graphic, I thought I can use a div or other element and than style it via css e.g. give borders or something... but I discovered that it wasn't as easy as I thought and I can't achieve it.

Here is what I need to get as a final result:

[image]

I'm interested in diagonal lines, ignore the background. Is there a way to replicate such lines with help of html or css?

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_transform_rotatez

Comment: Hi thanks, yeh I tried that before, but for some reason it didn't work, here is quick fiddle of what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/TVbrU/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Hope this helps you get started..!!` [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/63hSw/1/) here..

HTML

```
<body>      
        <div class="myDiv"></div>        
        <div class="myDiv"></div>
        <div class="myDiv"></div>        
        <div class="myDiv"></div>        
        <div class="myDiv"></div>
        <div class="myDiv"></div>        
        <div class="myDiv"></div>
        <div class="myDiv"></div>                
</body>​
```

CSS

```
.myDiv {
background-color: none;
border: solid 2px #AAA;
margin: 30px;
height: 5px;
-webkit-transform: rotateZ(115deg); // Chrome
-moz-transform: rotateZ(115deg) // Mozilla Firefox
}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The link which I mentioned is not someone's blog post its a link to jsfiddle.net where we can edit, execute and save the html for live demo which gives a better explanation..

Comment: If you need to share just a link add it as a comment

Comment: I dont have that much reputation to add it as comment that's why I posted it as an answer..

Comment: for adding comment you need no reputation at all. I just posted the first comment because there was only a link nothing more. Now your answer is ok. It have more description.

Comment: @MidhunMP: to post comments on other people's answers/questions (you can *always* comment on your *own* questions/answers) requires a [rep of >=50](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 5):

You can do what you ask using css `background-image: repeating-linear-gradient()`

Lea Verou has a great gallery: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/

You can modify [diagonial-stripes](http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#diagonal-stripes) pattern and get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
http://www.patternify.com/
U can make patterns just like that here, and convert it to CSS to use for your background.

Comment: Please offer an answer to the question, even if only a summary of what's found byfollowing the link; don't simply offer a link to an external site. Stack Overflow should be self-contained.

Comment: @DavidThomas When the person asking the question is too lazy to even attempt an answer, this is all they deserve. StackOverflow shouldn't a freelance worker website. We should only encourage developers to help them fix what they couldn't. They should at least try, that would encourage us to write something a bit more substantial. :)

Comment: @Shahil it's really disrespectful of you to call me lazy here, as I did attempt several solutions, which I thought should work e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/TVbrU/ I did not include them here because they were not working.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup I want to apologize if I came across as being disrespectful. My intention was just to make a point to David who was going around down voting posts. :)

Comment: If you didn't feel the question merited an answer, don't answer. If, however, you want to answer then you should, to my mind, provide a proper answer. As it is I stand by my down-vote.

Comment: @IlyaKnaup
I've added something at http://jsfiddle.net/TVbrU/22/ This now works in firefox, but I didn't get it to rotate on Chrome.